# How to determine if this series converges absolutely/conditionally or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\Sigma_{n=2}^{\infty} \ln (1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})
$$

?

I thought that $\ln (1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$ behaves like $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ when $n\to \infty$ but I don't know how to use it, since the limit comparison test only applies when both sequences are positive...

Will you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\ln\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k}\right) + \ln\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right) = \ln\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{2k}\right) + \ln\left(\dfrac{2k}{2k+1} \right) = \ln(1) = 0$$
Hence the sum converges to zero. However, it doesn't converge absolutely, since we have
$$\left \vert \ln\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k}\right) \right \vert + \left \vert\ln\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right) \right \vert= 2\ln\left(1+\dfrac1{2k}\right) \sim \dfrac1k$$
which when summed up diverges.

---

**EDIT**

To elaborate a bit more,
$$A_n = \sum_{k=2}^n \ln\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^k}k\right)= \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if n is odd}\\
\ln\left(\dfrac{n+1}n\right) & \text{ if n is even}\end{cases}$$
Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = 0$